# Swift 2.0 Core Spotlight API - search only for title

Tags: swift, api, spotlight, ios9

I'am testing the new Core Sportlight API feature in iOS 9. The indexing process works well but is there a way to define that the indexed Item should only get searched by the "title" Attribute instead of "title" and "description"?

Maybe you already have some more informations than me.

Comment: I do have a similar requirement, my app have items, and notes, both are searchable. For notes, I would like to display the item name as the description. However, this makes it when I search for something that matches the item, both the item and all its notes will appear. It sounds like Apple doesn't want us to put anything other than real "description" into the description field.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried doing this using Objective C, and it works perfectly.

It depends on what implementation of "CSSearchableAttributeSet" is used.
In obj C, there are many implementations of CSSearchableAttributeSet like

1. CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_General
2. CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_Document
3. CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_Image
   and others.

I have used CSSearchableItemAttributeSet_General in my code and I'm able to search by the title attribute only. In fact, that particular implementation of CSSearchableItemAttributeSet doesn't even have a "description" attribute.

So depending on what type of object you want to search for, you can use the particular implementation.

I believe it would be the same equivalent class in swift as well.

-Tejas

Comment: I can search by the title attribute only if i don't provide contentDescription attribute, too. But i would like to have the contentDescription and would like to search only in the title. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you would want that? 
I think that the content description is also for indexing based on a particular term. 
You could use the "theme" or "kind" attribute to store string data which wouldn't come up for searching.

Comment: Yes there is a reason: For example i have 100 indexed items with a fixed name (e.g. "Color") an a counting index. That is my title.

In my description i have some other numbers like RGB values (e.g. "230,78,123", "22,178,210", ...). Every indexed item has other description numbers. 

When i now serach for "Color 78" not only the item with title "Color 78" appears - also some other items with this number in the description. If there are enough with number "78" for example my searched item "Color 78" did not appear in the first four results - that's bad cause that was what i'm searching for.

Comment: Okay I'm not sure thats how its meant to be used. The CSSearchableItem that you create, takes the CSAttributeSet as the metadata that it can index on. Any reason why you would need to store some value in the attribute set like the RGB value that you mentioned, yet not want it to be searched? Because once you get the call to your application from spotlight result, all you get is the unique identifier only. All those other attributes you had is anyways not available.

Comment: I filed a radar on this point - to be able to mark e.g contentDescription as nonSearchable (the same way you can with custom attribute keys). I can see many use cases where you want to provide a description to aid choosing the correct result, but without having the description influence the results. I suggest you do the same @KevinLieser (21505746 for any Apple folk)

Comment: @TejasHS, How do you "use" one implementation?